# Transform list of objects into csv using dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave

I am trying to transform a list of objects to csv using the following code in dataweave:

```
%dw 1.0
%type company = :object {class: "java.util.ArrayList"}
%input payload application/java
%output application/csv
---
{
    name: payload.name,
    address: payload.address
} as :company
```

The below is the output that I get when I execute the above data weave code.

```
name,name
testName,testName2
testAddress,testAddress2
```

whilst I am expecting the following: (Sample data)

```
name,address
testName,testAddress
testName2,testAddress2
```

Help me understand to what am I missing in the data weave component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general terms, when using DataWeave you describe your output using a canonical representation which is more or less a super-set of other data formats.

To generate a CSV output you need to generate an array of objects.
Each of these objects represent a CSV row.
Objects in DataWeave are sets of key-value pairs

The mapping should be something like:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/csv
---
payload map {
    name: $.name,
    address: $.address
}
```

The `map` operation here generates an object with a `name` and `address` for each entry in the list. `$` represents the implicit variable under iteration (each list entry).

Note: The `%input payload application/java` directive is not necessary since the content-type for your input (JSON, XML, CSV, etc) is taken from the mule message when it is set, and it defaults to java if it's not present.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

**INPUT:**

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
[{
    name: "nameInput",
    address: "addressInput"
}]
```

**MAPPING:**

```
%dw 1.0 %output application/csv
---
payload
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
name,address
nameInput,addressInput
```

Comment: Thanks :) Even though it works it is not what I want. I want to specify the fields that I want in the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

A splitter with xpath as evaluator should do the trick...like:

```
<splitter evaluator="xpath" expression="/document/article"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, similar as @Tilo descirbed in his [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32204498/6017600), but I had to put extra "**flatten**" because I had Array of Arrays as my input.

**MAPPING:**

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/csv
---
flatten payload
```