# xml to List conversion in mule esb using data weave component

Tags: xml, csv, mule, datamapper, dataweave

I have the following xml as my input

### InputXML:

```
<Orders>
<Order>
  <sample id="1"></sample>
  <sample id="2"></sample>
  .
  .
  .
  .    
 </Order>
<Order>
  <sample id="1"></sample>
  <sample id="2"></sample>
  .
  .
  .
  .    
 </Order>
<Order>
   <sample id="1"></sample>
   <sample id="2"></sample>
   .
   .
   .
   .    
</Order>
.
.
.
.
</Orders>
```

I need to send this xml to the **batch** component in my flow. My batch should accept each record in the following manner

```
  Record1:1st Order
  Record2:2nd Order
  Record3:3rd Order
  .
  .
  .
  .
```

Now please let me know what coding do I need to do in my **DataWeave(Transform message)** component to acheive this scenario.I tried multiple ways but no result. I am trying this from past few days and got tired. Please help me in this regard!! Please share the sample code.

Output should look like:

```
1) Order  ---- Object
          sample-----Object
              -sampleValue(i.e; value of 'sample' element)
              -sampleidValue(i.e; value of attribute of 'sample')
          sample-----Object
              -sampleValue(i.e; value of 'sample' element)
              -sampleidValue(i.e; value of attribute of 'sample')
            .
            .
            .
            .
2) Order  ---- Object
          sample-----Object
              -sampleValue(i.e; value of 'sample' element)
              -sampleidValue(i.e; value of attribute of 'sample')
          sample-----Object
              -sampleValue(i.e; value of 'sample' element)
              -sampleidValue(i.e; value of attribute of 'sample')
            .
            .
            .
            .
```

### Inside Batch:

I do have another dataweave component that transforms this collection to csv.

The input of this dataweave component is each object from this collection. The data is extracted from this object and written to the CSV file.

### Updated Question:

The issue I am facing is Each Object in the collection is of structure

```
 Order  ---- Object
          sample1-----Object
              -sampleValue(i.e; value of 'sample' element)
              -sampleidValue(i.e; value of attribute of 'sample')
          sample2-----Object
              -sampleValue(i.e; value of 'sample' element)
              -sampleidValue(i.e; value of attribute of 'sample')
            .
            .
            .
            .
```

But the output of my CSV should be:

```
        sample1.sampleValue   sample3.sampleValue   .    .       .       .(this is 'Order1' object)
            sample2.sampleValue   sample6.sampleValue   .    .       .       .(this is 'Order2' object)
.
.
.
.
```

I am not able to get the output this way in the CSV file. bcz my 'sample' is also a List of Objects. I tried this in both **DataMapper and DataWeave** also. Please help me out how to extract the values.

Comment: Please do comment incase of any clarification in the question. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the output format.Explain with an example

Comment: @NaveenRaj

Hi,

My output should look like:

Comment: @NaveenRaj
I have a batch process in my flow. As, we know batch accepts only ArrayList of Objects(as records). So, I need to convert the Input XML to the CollectionMap.
Each Object must have data like:
------------------------------------------

Comment: 'Order  ---- Object
               sample-----Object
                   -sampleValue(i.e; value of 'sample' element)
                   -sampleidValue(i.e; value of attribute of 'sample')
                  sample-----Object
                    -sampleValue(i.e; value of 'sample' element)
                    -sampleidValue(i.e; value of attribute of 'sample')
                 .
                 .
                 .

              Order  ---- Object
                    sample-----Object                         .
                         .
                         .'

Comment: Not sure why you are doing transformation in input phase ( Based on requirement). You can try this Use Java component in Input phase and return as list of order to ProcessPhase. Can handle logic for all transformation using dataweaver in process Phase.

Comment: @star

I have updated my question pls look into it

Comment: @star

My requirement is something related to this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202884/transform-list-of-objects-into-csv-using-dataweave

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please find the below Data Weave

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/csv separator=" "
---

payload.Orders.*Order map {
SampleValue1:$.sample.@id,
SampleValue2:$.sample.@id,
SampleValue3:$.sample.@id   
}
```

The below is the X%dw 1.0

### %output application/csv separator=" "

```
payload.Orders.*Order map {
SampleValue1:$.sample.@id,
SampleValue2:$.sample.@id,
SampleValue3:$.sample.@id   
}
```

The below is the xml that I have used based on the xml that is shared in the question.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Orders>
<Order>
  <sample id="1">test</sample>
</Order>
<Order>
  <sample id="1">test</sample>
</Order>
<Order>
   <sample id="1">test</sample>
</Order>
</Orders>
```

Hope this helps!