# Dataweave XML to XML mapping

Tags: xml, mule, mule-studio, dataweave

### My input XML:

```
<Orders>
<Order><sample att="a1">b1</sample></Order>
<Order><sample att="a2">b2</sample></Order>
<Order><sample att="a3">b3</sample></Order>
.
.
.
.
</Orders>
```

### My Requirement:

```
<Orders>
<Order><sample>a1||b1</sample></Order>
<Order><sample>a2||b2</sample></Order>
<Order><sample>a3||b3</sample></Order>
.
.
.
.
</Orders>
```

I need to achieve this in the **dataweave component** . I have tried in datamapper also using some **Rules** option but no result. So, please help me in this. I need to achieve this in dataweave component. A code snippet with syntax would really helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the examples here and the documentation: http://mulesoft.github.io/data-weave/#_xml_to_json

It gives you examples on how to access xml attributes and elements etc. Here is a possible Dataweave script for your scenario

```
%dw 0.1
%input payload application/xml
%output application/xml
---
Orders: { (payload.Orders.*Order map {
     Order: {
        sample: $.@att ++ "||" ++ $.sample,
      }
 }) }
```

Comment: Ok thnx. Will try it and let you know it is working !!! Also can u pls make sometime in looking this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589875/xml-to-list-conversion-in-mule-esb-using-data-weave-component

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
%dw 0.1
%input payload application/xml
%output application/xml
---
Orders: { 
    (payload.Orders.*Order map {
        Order: {
           sample: $.@att ++ "||" ++ $.sample,
              }
        }
    ) 
}
```